# ∀ (for all) in voltmeter specification

Tags: voltage-measurement, symbol

I am working on a voltmeter and the tolerance for it is 0.25% ∀ 1 digit. I am not sure what exactly what this means. I am guessing if my value was 19.95 'for all' could mean I have a range of 19.94 and 19.96?[image]

Comment: You can write it as the HTML entity &forall; -- except in titles and comments, where you must paste the actual character: ∀

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like some kind of a font encoding error. A typical spec is 0.25% **+** 1 digit.

So a 19.95 input could read 19.80 to 20.01.

We often see a font error in pdf files where \$\Omega\$ is intended but it comes out as a W.

---

Edit: With enough of the manual now presented to access it on the net, we can come to a conclusion. As Dave Tweed suggested in a comment, it's from ±. The previous version to the current manual (3.2 vs. 4.0b) has the correct character.

[image]

Comment: ... or perhaps 0.25% ± 1 digit (HTML entity &plusmn;)

Comment: @DaveTweed Bingo. Previous version has ±.